# Lightbox2 doesnt like IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, overlay, lightbox2

view my page: http://tonyperson.com/art4art

click on the picture (woman study 01) in IE8 and the transparent black background does not go all the way down the page.... any help is appreciated!

I have tried many things in css like changing the height to 100% for the overlay div, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Change the `position: absolute` on your `.content` div to `position: relative`.

The absolute positioning of it takes it (and thus the entire page's contents) out of the flow, collapsing the `body` down to a height of 0. You can verify that by checking e.g. `document.body.scrollHeight`.

Since Lightbox then sees the body has no height, it only bothers adding the overlay to one screen-full.

Edit: As a work-around for the problem noted in the comments (the overlay still doesn't cover everything when the lightbox extends below the bottom of the original page), you could add some extra padding to the bottom of the page.

Comment: still having a "broken placement of the bottom element with the closing tag and title" now. Also, It does not go all the way to the bottom of the screen. But your suggestion did help it go most of the way! :)

Comment: I see what you mean. I think that's a bug in Lightbox. The overlay still only covers the height of the original page. When the lightbox/image being opened extends below the original bottom of the page, the overlay doesn't extend to cover that part too (well, it does in Firefox and Safari)... Its `getPageSize()` function isn't quite cross-browser enough. The most reliable way I could find to get the proper height is by using `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`, but Lightbox doesn't use that.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tricky trick here, just convert the position:absolut to position:fixed so the overlay at a screen size can be moved by the directional bars when going down or up, it will give you the feeling that overlay covered all the page.